# NAO laser head urg_node connection problem

Tags: ros, laser, urg-node, scan, nao

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi. I'm trying to use NAO laser head with urg_node, but there is connection problem. I'm trying to connect with Ehternet and always have same problem

```
 [FATAL] [1397748302.090283298]: Could not open network Hokuyo:
192.168.0.10:10940
could not open ethernet port.
```

Also i used different ip-diapason address: default, 192.168.0.0/24, 192.168.1.0/24 there is no connection to laser. (to connect laser use NAO ip, default ip (192.168.0.10) as said [here](http://answers.ros.org/question/62830/hokuyo-utm-30lx-ew-not-detected-in-ubuntu-or-pc/)) What i'm doing wrong?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/154316/nao-laser-head-urg_node-connection-problem/) by [antongepard](https://answers.ros.org/users/13456/antongepard/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2014-04-17

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Do you have details about the Nao laser head you are using? I'm pretty sure that the Hokuyo laser is not connected via ethernet but a serial device over USB (the only one I know with the URG04LX is definitely not network-enabled). So you can't connect to it over network. Instead you need to cross-compile hokuyo_node or urg_node for the Nao and run the driver locally on the robot.

---

Originally posted by [AHornung](https://answers.ros.org/users/141/ahornung/) with karma: 5904 on 2014-04-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0